# Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as an array in getStaticPaths for /posts/[...slug]

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a problem with the 'getStaticPaths' function. When I try to get a dynamic display with a parameter it shows me as error: Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as an array in getStaticPaths for /posts/[...slug]

In My utils.js file got this function read the files

```
export function getPostsFiles() {
const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), "posts");

return fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory);
}
```

In my page [...slug]

```
export function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const { slug } = params;

  const postData = getPostData(slug);

  return {
    props: {
      post: postData,
    },
    revalidate: 600,
  };
}

export function getStaticPaths() {
  const postFilenames = getPostsFiles();

  const slugs = postFilenames.map((fileName) => fileName.replace(/\.md$/, ""));
  const parameters = slugs.map((slug) => ({ params: { slug: slug } }));

  return {
    paths: parameters,
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

Comment: If `slug` is meant to be a single string you should just use a normal (non-catch-all) dynamic route, i.e. `/posts/[slug]`. Otherwise, you need to pass an array (not just a string) to the `slug` params in `getStaticPaths` when using a catch-all dynamic route.